# changing Angular's filter symbol '|'

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to change Angular's filter symbol **|**?  I'm looking for something similar to the following method for changing start and end symbols for variable interpolation:

```
$interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
$interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
```

Thanks!